# Rollup via CLI: Treating as external dependency

Tags: javascript, bundle, rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle everything into one single file with rollupjs.

`main.js` file:

```
import * as ex from 'example-export';

ex.alertMe();
```

`example-export.js` file:

```
export function alertMe() {
    alert('alert!');
};
```

The command below and it's response:

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~/dev/sketch/experiment/socketio$ rollup ./public/js/main.js --output ./public/js/bundle.js --format iife --sourcemap inline
Treating 'example-export' as external dependency
No name was provided for external module 'example-export' in options.globals – guessing 'ex'
```

The `bundle.js` file produced:

```
(function (ex) {
'use strict';

ex.alertMe();

}(ex));
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiYnVuZGxlLmpzIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyJtYWluLmpzIl0sInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbImltcG9ydCAqIGFzIGV4IGZyb20gJ2V4YW1wbGUtZXhwb3J0JztcblxuZXguYWxlcnRNZSgpOyJdLCJuYW1lcyI6W10sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiOzs7QUFFQSxFQUFFLENBQUMsT0FBTyxFQUFFLDs7In0=
```

I was expecting the `example-export` module to be included in the `bundle.js` file. Since this is really new stuff the internet lacks proper examples of this.

I expect the issue has something to do with the `--name` argument https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Command-Line-Interface#usage. I cannot however figure out how it's supposed to be used. And let's say if I have multiple exports and imports, how will that look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Relative path

If the file is in the same directory:

```
import * as ex from './example-export';
```

### Via NODE_PATH

If the NODE_PATH env variable is set, then you may add a path from that.

- If the `NODE_PATH` is equal to `/home/karl/myprojects/mynodeproject/`
- The library your trying to access is located at `/home/karl/myprojects/mynodeproject/src/lib/my_library.js`
- And the file you are writing which is currently trying to import `my_library` is at `/home/karl/myprojects/mynodeproject/src/index.js`

Then you can use the following in `index.js`:

```
import * as ex from 'src/lib/example-export';
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the example through the Rollup playground page, only thing I needed to change to get it working was change the

`import * as ex from 'example-export';`

to

`import * as ex from './example-export';`

[Take a look here](http://rollupjs.org/?shareable=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)